# Matter-js. Lograr que objeto aumente aceleración en cada rebote

Tags: javascript, html, matter.js

estoy intentando hacer un juego donde una bola rebota contra una plataforma. Quiero lograr que cada vez que la bola rebote, tenga una altura mayor al rebote previo y mas aceleración, de forma que sea algo acumulativo,es decir, cada vez que rebota contra la plataforma, sube a una altura mayor y sube mas rápido.

```js
// module aliases
const Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Events = Matter.Events,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
});

// create runner
var runner = Runner.create();
Runner.run(runner, engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);

var ball = Bodies.circle(400, 100, 5, { restitution: 1 });
ball.label = 'ball';
var wall = Bodies.rectangle(400, 550, 200, 30, { isStatic: true });
wall.label = 'wall';

World.add(engine.world, [ball, wall]);

function detectCollision(event) {
    var pairs = event.pairs;
    if (pairs[0].bodyA.label == 'wall' && pairs[0].bodyB.label == 'ball') {
        // Aqui iria el codigo supongo
    }
}

Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', detectCollision);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra forma de hacerlo es jugar con la velocidad, al cambiarla en la colisión envía más alto y más rápido. Puedes activar la línea del log que he añadido en la función para ver los datos de la velocidad en cada colisión. Según la lógica física, en un sistema con gravedad para que tras las colisiones aumente la altura en sucesivos rebotes en un elemento elástico debemos aportarle energía y si es posible minimizar la fricción.
Para que este efecto sea más claro en la bola he seteado a 0 la fricción del elemento y la fricción del aire.

```js
// module aliases
const Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Events = Matter.Events,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
});

// create runner
var runner = Runner.create();
Runner.run(runner, engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);

var ball = Bodies.circle(400, 50, 5, { restitution: 1, friction:0, frictionAir:0 });
ball.label = 'ball';
var wall = Bodies.rectangle(400, 550, 300, 30, { isStatic: true });
wall.label = 'wall';

World.add(engine.world, [ball, wall]);

var n = 0;
function detectCollision(event) {
    Body.setVelocity(ball,{
          x: ball.velocity.x,
          y: -(ball.velocity.y+1)
        });
    //console.log("coll" + " vel" + ball.speed);   
    
}

Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', detectCollision);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Esto también me ha funcionado. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En teoría el valor de `restitution` debe estar entre 0 y 1, pero aunque lo pongas en 1 no hay un 100% de eficiencia en el rebote, parece que se calcula de manera aleatoria una leve pérdida de energía cinética en cada bote.

Pero parece que la librería no es tan estricta como la documentación dice, porque poniendo valores superiores a 1 se consigue aumentar el bote.

Con 1.5 parece que aún se pierde algo de energía, pero con 1.8 el bote es claramente más alto en cada colisión:

```js
// module aliases
const Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Events = Matter.Events,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
});

// create runner
var runner = Runner.create();
Runner.run(runner, engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);

var ball = Bodies.circle(400, 100, 5, { restitution: 1.8 });
ball.label = 'ball';
var wall = Bodies.rectangle(300, 550, 600, 30, { isStatic: true });
wall.label = 'wall';

World.add(engine.world, [ball, wall]);

function detectCollision(event) {
    var pairs = event.pairs;
    if (pairs[0].bodyA.label == 'wall' && pairs[0].bodyB.label == 'ball') {
        // Aqui iria el codigo supongo
    }
}

Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', detectCollision);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Esto me ha funcionado, pero sucede que cuando la bola alcanza cierta aceleración, traspasa objetos con los que se supone debería colisionar. Aunque esto es un problema de continuous collision detection (CCD la librería. Hablan mas sobre esto en: https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/5